# how to separate the key(YearMonth) in reduce function in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

this map-reduce is to compute average temperature per year and month for the example in "Hadoop: the Definite Guide"

the output should be

year[TAB]month[TAB]average_temperature

Since the keys(year+month) already merge, would it be possible to use substring() and context.write(year[TAB]month[TAB]average_temperature)? or what would be the common way to handle this issue? like the following(which is incorrect)?

context.write(key.toString().substring(0, 4),key.toString().substring(4, 6) ,average);

```
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<TemperatureAveragingPair> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int temp = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (TemperatureAveragingPair pair : values) {
        temp += pair.getTemp().get();
        count += pair.getCount().get();
    }
    average.set(temp / count);
    context.write(key, average);
}
```

full code reference is here.
https://github.com/bbejeck/hadoop-algorithms/blob/master/src/bbejeck/mapred/aggregation/AverageTemperatureReducer.java

Comment: Can u point to the driver class ?

Comment: is it what you mean?https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/ch05/src/main/java/v7/MaxTemperatureDriver.java

Comment: Can you add a few sample data ?

Comment: Year[TAB]Month[TAB]Temperature,

1995[TAB]2[TAB]-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afer going through classes, a few things seems odd to me.

First, your Mapper output `<Text, IntWritable>` doesn't comply with the Reducer/Combiner input `<Text, TemperatureAveragingPair>`. These should be in sync, else the job will fail without showing any problem in compilation.

You said *'Since the keys(year+month) already merge'*, I assume that the following statement in `NcdcRecordParser` fetches the year+month(definitely in yyMM format):

```
 year = record.substring(15, 19);
```

But the mentioned statement contradicts it :

```
context.write(key.toString().substring(0, 4),key.toString().substring(4, 6), average);
```

which suggests a yyyyMM format. Nowhere you seem to be adding month the to the year string in the previous case.

Anyway lets get to the point. You are right, you can use `substring` method to separate the year and month as shown. But for that you have to emit a key of the same format from `Mapper`. Next, you don't need to use `TemperatureAveragingPair` as value for `Reducer`, a simple `IntWritable` will do the trick and remove the anomalies. Now it will look something like :

```
private Text tabKey = new Text();
private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
                 throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     int temp = 0;
     int count = 0;
     for (IntWritable value : values) {
        temp += value.get();
        count ++;
      }
   average.set(temp / count);

   builder.setLength(0);
   builder.append(key.toString());
   builder.insert(4, "\t");       
   tabKey.setText(builder.toString());

   context.write(tabKey, average);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still `context.write(key, average)` emits YearMonth[TAB] temperature. How to emit Year[TAB]Month[TAB]Temperature?
`context.write(key.toString().substring(0, 4),key.toString().substring(4, 6), average);` is not working.